# Connecting an FM radio receiver circuit to a speaker via 3.5 mm audio jack?

Tags: frequency-modulation

As an experiment and for educational purposes, I wanted to build and connect an FM receiver to some old computer speakers via a 3.5 mm audio jack.

So I tried building a circuit like this on a bread board

[My FM receiver circuit with pre-amp to 3.5 mm audio jack](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+0.000005+5.934295036739208+57+5+50%0A201+-192+176+-192+256+0+88000000+100+5+200%0At+0+224+-48+224+0+1+-6.200854980431619+0.01789568053872893+100%0At+96+288+48+288+0+1+6.200854980431619+6.218750660970348+100%0At+224+288+272+288+0+1+0+0+100%0Ar+272+160+96+160+0+20000%0Ar+272+160+272+240+0+10000%0Ar+272+240+208+240+0+1000000%0Ac+0+160+0+224+0+2.1999999999999998e-11+6.200854980431619%0Al+48+160+48+224+0+0.001+0.022719377923463877%0Ag+48+336+48+368+0%0Aw+0+224+48+224+0%0Aw+48+272+48+224+0%0Aw+-48+208+-48+160+0%0Aw+-48+160+0+160+0%0Aw+0+160+48+160+0%0AA+48+160+48+112+0+1+40+5+0+0+0.5%0Aw+96+160+96+288+0%0Aw+96+160+48+160+0%0Aw+48+304+48+336+0%0Aw+-48+240+-48+336+0%0Aw+-48+336+48+336+0%0Ac+96+288+208+288+0+1.0000000000000001e-7+0%0Aw+208+240+208+288+0%0Aw+208+288+224+288+0%0Aw+272+272+272+240+0%0Aw+48+336+272+336+0%0Aw+272+304+272+336+0%0Ac+272+240+336+240+0+1.0000000000000001e-7+0%0AO+336+240+384+240+0%0Av+432+336+432+160+0+0+40+4+0+0+0.5%0Aw+272+160+432+160+0%0Aw+272+336+432+336+0%0Ao+28+64+0+4098+5+0.1+0+1%0A)

*Note: The 22pf capacitor on the far left is actually a variable capacitor that I can adjust between 8pf and 40pf.  And hopefully, I used falstad correctly to depict my actual circuit.*

The circuit on the left consisting of the two transistors is something I found in most FM receiver tutorials.  And I figure I couple it to a NPN transistor pre-amplifier circuit on the right.  I then connect the output to the tip of a 3.5mm jack.

When I power up the circuit, my speakers are silent.  If I touch the antenna with my fingers, my speakers produce a low frequency hum.  I disconnected the 3.5 mm jack and hooked up an oscilloscope probe to the output and confirmed there is no signal...in fact I don't even see any noise waveform unless I touch the antenna with my fingers.

Does anyone have suggestions on what I might do next to receive an FM radio signal or at least noise from a blank FM channel?

Comment: So... you are actually trying to build an FM reciever, rather than trying to connect the output of an FM receiver to a computer speaker.  Your title should then be "How do I  build an FM receiver", which is probably too broad a question for this site.

Comment: A question here about debugging a circuit would need to include the schematic, component values (and for a radio their type and the overall physical construction) within the *body* of the post itself, not as a link.